# Cropping and scaling bitmap efficiently 2018?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide, bitmapfactory

We are having difficulty with bitmaps in our product. Our goal is to  take picture fast and display it/crop immediately. The problem is - image has to be in a good quality, has to be cropped well and fast. I personally tried the code below and it does reduce memory usage by ~ 2-3 times. Still, we would like to know more efficient way. Should we always transfer imageArray[] instead of actual bitmaps between our custom frames processing(using Fotoapparat library, because of its ability to efficiently display full screen camera View) and ImageViews? **We are open to use Glide or any other tool to crop, or load bitmap if that would be more efficient.** Our current code for image retrieving from cameraView frames(this reduces usage ~ 2-3 times):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 50, out);
byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length, options);
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, (int)(width/1.5),(int)(height/1.5));
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length, options);
```

Then we crop this Bitmap with method below (this seems inefficient in 2018):

```
resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(original, 0,0,width, height);
```

Also, what about threads? Should we use AsyncTask, Executors or any other ways for cropping/showing bitmap? I personally always use RxJava, however our core product must be as lightweight as possible :)

Comment: All the logic of reducing the size and stuff, do it in background thread using executors or asynctask, once that is done post it to the main thread. This should take off the load from main thread

Comment: @PrashanthVerma really thank you for quick response. Should I use this code for cropping, and decoding from frames? Or are there better ways? :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternatives

If you're on API level 10+ you can alternatively use `BitmapRegionDecoder` which does the cropping and downsampling in one step, probably in native.

As a totally different approach you can also try converting the `data` directly to a `Bitmap` and then using a `Canvas` to draw some part of the original Bitmap onto a new cropped version, doing scaling via the Canvas' transformation matrix.

#### Quality

> image has to be in a good quality, has to be cropped well and fast.

Your first step where you compress to `quality=50`, you're losing a lot of information. Then later when you create the new Bitmap, you do an up-scaling which also affects the quality; in my opinion cropping only makes sense if the resulting image is actually smaller.

#### Efficiency

> Then we crop this Bitmap with method below (this seems inefficient in 2018)

Consider this: do you really need the Bitmap to be the exact size? It's probably much better to leave the Bitmap as the cropped size, have the smaller Bitmap in memory, upload the smaller Bitmap to the GPU and let the GPU rendering do the scaling. It's possible the `View` won't match the `Bitmap` size, so this will happen anyway.

#### Glide

Glide pretty much does the same thing at its core as your code (except the YUV bit). See [`Downsampler`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/bitmap/Downsampler.java), the difference is that it works with many input sources, formats and API levels, hence the size difference.

> our core product must be as lightweight as possible :)

Including an image loading library and forcing the user to include that as well goes against this. But at the same time do you really want to re-invent the wheel and write your own image loading library? For example Glide has a lot of pieces that can be replaced for custom behavior.

In my app I have a camera -> user crop selection -> cropped smaller Bitmap flow. I did something similar to yours, except using the disk instead of `ByteArrayOutputStream`, because the input can be huge and it would need to fit kind-of twice into memory for which there's no guarantee.

Comment: what an amazing answer... Can't express my gratitude. Still feel, that I am lost. After all reading and  researching I have two ways:
1. get byte[] array from camera view frame processor, use that data to create bitmap( I need bitmap height and weight to apply my multiple formula, it is different on devices), then use React to figure out dimensions  of cropped bitmap and then decodeRegion.. tried this solution, but is really slow.
2. would be to save frames to storage(as you recommended) and later decode it... but still slow in comparison with mine solution..
Can't find any examples :(